# Implementing boolean operations using decoders

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

Is it possible to implement boolean operation gates such as AND, OR NAND, etc. by using decoders? Further, is it possible to implement n-input AND, OR gates using decoders?

Comment: probably yes and yes ... almost anything is possible ... depends on what you mean by `decoder` ...  do you have any other questions?

Comment: How would one try to implement it that way? I tried but I am struggling with understanding how to get single output from the 4 outputs coming from 2-4 decoder.

Comment: You would take the output you need which implements the logic function you want.

Comment: @aebosnak then do not ask `is it possible?` ... ask `how is it done?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes active-high decoders)
Take a simplest `1->2` decoder. It is implementing two functions - `D0 = S'` and `D1=S`. So `D0` is your `NOT` function. And, well, you can't do anything else with it.

Let's take `2->4` decoder. It's functions are:

```
D0 = S0'S1'
D1 =....
........
```

and... we can stop here, because `D0` is exactly a `NOR` function which is known to be as a "universal gate" and can be used to implement any other logical function.

UPD: Example implementing OR:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRHy5c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see how your example works since there is 1 valid output coming from a 2-to-4 decoder for a NOR gate, so I understand the approach, but there's still something I quite don't understand: For example, when I try to implement an OR gate using a 2-to-4 decoder, there are 3 valid outputs coming from the decoder. Which one of these should I take as my result? Or do I have to take a single one of them as the result? I don't quite understand what to do.

Comment: @aebosnak No one is saying just one decoder is enough for every function. You will take two decoders, one will serve as NOT gate and one will serve as NOR. Cascaded they will give you OR.

Comment: I got it now, thanks.

Comment: No, to implement OR gate, you would take the one output that is active when both inputs are logic zeroes. Then that output will not be active if A, B or both are high. Invert output if needed, or use active low decoder.

Comment: Updated with example OR implementation. `AND` you get "for free" from `D3` of the first encoder.